# Generating frequency tables based on CSV dataset

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I am working on a project which crunches plain text files (`.lst`).

The name of the file names (`fileName`) are important because I'll extract `node` (e.g. `abessijn`) and `component` (e.g. `WR-P-E-A`) from them into a dataframe.

Examples:

```
abessijn.WR-P-E-A.lst
A-bom.WR-P-E-A.lst
acroniem.WR-P-E-C.lst
acroniem.WR-P-E-G.lst
adapter.WR-P-E-A.lst
adapter.WR-P-E-C.lst
adapter.WR-P-E-G.lst
```

Each file consists of one or more line. Each line consists of a sentence (inside `<sentence>` tags). Example (`abessijn.WR-P-E-A.lst`)

```
<sentence>Vooral mijn abessijn ruikt heerlijk kruidig .. : ) )</sentence>
<sentence>Mijn abessijn denkt daar heel anders over .. : ) ) Maar mijn kinderen richt ik ook niet af , zit niet in mijn bloed .</sentence>
```

From each line I extract the sentence, do some small modifications to it, and call it `sentence`. Up next is an element called `leftContext`, which takes the first part of the split between `node` (e.g. `abessijn`) and the sentence it came from. Finally, from `leftContext` I get `precedingWord`, which is the word preceding `node` in `sentence`, or the right most word in `leftContext` (with some limitations such as the option of a compound formed with a hyphen). Example:

```
ID | filename             | node | component | precedingWord      | leftContext                               |  sentence
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    adapter.WR-P-P-F.lst  adapter  WR-P-P-F   aanpassingseenheid  Een aanpassingseenheid (                      Een aanpassingseenheid ( adapter ) , 
2    adapter.WR-P-P-F.lst  adapter  WR-P-P-F   toestel             Het toestel (                                 Het toestel ( adapter ) draagt zorg voor de overbrenging van gegevens
3    adapter.WR-P-P-F.lst  adapter  WR-P-P-F   de                  de aansluiting tussen de sensor en de         de aansluiting tussen de sensor en de adapter , 
4    airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst   airbag   WS-U-E-A   den                 ja voor den                                   ja voor den airbag op te pompen eh :p
5    airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst   airbag   WS-U-E-A   ne                  Dobby , als ze valt heeft ze dan wel al ne    Dobby , als ze valt heeft ze dan wel al ne airbag hee
```

That dataframe is exported as `dataset.csv`.

After that, the intention of my project comes at hand: I create a frequency table that takes `node` and `precedingWord` into account. From a variable I define `neuter` and `non_neuter`, e.g (in Python)

```
neuter = ["het", "Het"]
non_neuter = ["de","De"]
```

and a rest category `unspecified`. When `precedingWord` is an item from the list, assign it to the variable. Example of a frequency table output:

```
node    |   neuter   | nonNeuter   | unspecified
-------------------------------------------------
A-bom       0          4             2
acroniem    3          0             2
act         3          2             1
```

The frequency list is exported as `frequencies.csv`.

I came up with the following script ([paste](http://pastebin.com/rPFJKuBV)) to do that:

```python
import os, pandas as pd, numpy as np, regex as re

from glob import glob
from datetime import datetime
from html import unescape

start_time = datetime.now()

# Create empty dataframe with correct column names
columnNames = ["fileName", "component", "precedingWord", "node", "leftContext", "sentence" ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((0,len(columnNames))), columns=columnNames)

# Create correct path where to fetch files
subdir = "rawdata"
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.pardir, subdir))

# "Cache" regex
# See http://stackoverflow.com/q/452104/1150683
p_filename = re.compile(r"[./\\]")

p_sentence = re.compile(r"<sentence>(.*?)</sentence>")
p_typography = re.compile(r" (?:(?=[.,:;?!) ])|(?<=\( ))")
p_non_graph = re.compile(r"[^\x21-\x7E\s]")
p_quote = re.compile(r"\"")
p_ellipsis = re.compile(r"\.{3}(?=[^ ])")

p_last_word = re.compile(r"^.*\b(?<!-)(\w+(?:-\w+)*)[^\w]*$", re.U)

# Loop files in folder
for file in glob(path+"\\*.lst"):
    with open(file, encoding="utf-8") as f:
        [n, c] = p_filename.split(file.lower())[-3:-1]
        fn = ".".join([n, c])
        for line in f:
            s = p_sentence.search(unescape(line)).group(1)
            s = s.lower()
            s = p_typography.sub("", s)
            s = p_non_graph.sub("", s)
            s = p_quote.sub("'", s)
            s = p_ellipsis.sub("... ", s)

            if n in re.split(r"[ :?.,]", s):
                lc = re.split(r"(^| )" + n + "( |[!\",.:;?})\]])", s)[0]

                pw = p_last_word.sub("\\1", lc)

                df = df.append([dict(fileName=fn, component=c, 
                                   precedingWord=pw, node=n, 
                                   leftContext=lc, sentence=s)])
            continue

# Reset indices
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# Export dataset
df.to_csv("dataset/py-dataset.csv", sep="\t", encoding="utf-8")

# Let's make a frequency list
# Create new dataframe

# Define neuter and non_neuter
neuter = ["het"]
non_neuter = ["de"]

# Create crosstab
df.loc[df.precedingWord.isin(neuter), "gender"] = "neuter"
df.loc[df.precedingWord.isin(non_neuter), "gender"] = "non_neuter"
df.loc[df.precedingWord.isin(neuter + non_neuter)==0, "gender"] = "rest"

freqDf = pd.crosstab(df.node, df.gender)

freqDf.to_csv("dataset/py-frequencies.csv", sep="\t", encoding="utf-8")

# How long has the script been running?
time_difference = datetime.now() - start_time
print("Time difference of", time_difference)
```

*I'm running Python in 32 bit, because I'd like to use the [nltk module](http://www.nltk.org/) in the future and they discourage users to use 64 bit.*

Seeing that the goal of Python was to make everything go smoothly, I was confused. **The goal is to beat a similar R script in execution speed.** I read Python was fast, so where did I go wrong? A colleague advised me to use Python which might be a faster case. I know you can't simply compare two languages that way, each has its merits. But in this specific case it seemed to me that Python ought to be faster in data crunching. I figured that when both scripts are equally well optimised, Python should be faster in this case. However, my current Python code is badly optimised whereas my R script is decent enough.

Please tell me if I'm completely wrong. If someone could help me use some higher hierarchy functions as proposed on SO (imap, ifilter...) **and explaining them** that would be great.

What is the problem? Is Python slower in reading files and lines, or in doing regexes? Or is R simply better equipped to dealing with dataframes and can't it be beaten by pandas? *Or* is my code simply badly optimised and should Python indeed be the victor?

You can download the test data I used [*here*](http://bramvanroy.be/files/testdata.zip).

I'm a bit of a beginner, so please take the time to explain how they work and/or why they're better.

Comment: `The goal is to beat a similar R script in execution speed. I read Python was fast, so where did I go wrong?` If I had a nickel for every time somebody stated something along those lines... A language being fast doesn't mean every implementation in the 'faster' language is going to beat the implementations in the 'slower' languages. It's a fallacy.

Comment: A week ago (on SO) I told you to remove the data frame append operation (the most time consuming part of your code) and split the algorithm into pure functions. And I told you to get a free copy of PyCharm to help make your code cleaner and profile it when needed. The advices are still here. Moreover, your variables are poorly named. I know you've got a `dict` call that kinda clarifies the names, but it take one to walk through a lot of lines before he gets to that "clarification". The overall approach is too imperative in the worst sense possible. The code is a problem generator.

Comment: @EliKorvigo I'm aware of that. As I told you then, I couldn't get it to work with higher hierarchy functions such as `imap` so I came to ask for an imporvement here. I figured people proficient in Python would be able to do an overall better job than I could. And they did! See answers below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Speed comparisons are always a good thing, but it can be tricky to determine what is actually being compared.  I think it's premature to decide that the comparison is "Python" vs. "R" without a lot of work to verify that all the libraries you use and functions you write are reasonably optimized for each language.

One of the strengths of python is a pretty good set of line profiling tools.  I like [`line_profiler`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler/), because it works in IPython notebooks, a format I find convenient for "real time" coding and tooling around.

I used line profiling to run a (Python 2 version of) your code, and I found that one single line in your script was responsible for 94.5% of the execution time.  Can you guess what it is?  It was this one:

```
df = df.append([dict(fileName=fn, component=c, 
                                       precedingWord=pw, node=n, 
                                       leftContext=lc, sentence=s)])
```

I'm not a veteran of pandas but I think it's safe to say that building a data frame row-by-row in pandas is not very efficient.

How did I refactor your code to run in Python 2 and ran `line_profiler` on it?  Essentially I just wrapped everything you wrote into a dummy function called `run_code()` and called the line profiler on that function.  For Python 2:

- I had to modify how you were parsing your directory (I use `os.listdir()`instead of `grob` stuff)
- I had to `import codec` because Python 2 isn't natively able to Unicode the same way that Python 3 is.

The bottom-line results: *your code took about 25.6 seconds (on my machine) to run, but simply filling the Pandas dataframe by column after parsing was done instead of row-by-row during parsing took 1.2 seconds.*  **This simple modification led to speedup of more than 20×!**  You could probably get even faster by pre-allocating Numpy structured arrays for each column, and then using those to fill a dataframe by column.

In addition to the timing issue, there are a number of other aspects of your code that you may want to consider revising:

- Variable names are confusing (what is `s`, etc.) and don't always follow PEP8.  (Avoid `camelCase` and use `snake_case` instead, etc.)
- For simple timing, consider the `timeit` module instead of `datetime`.  (Of course, the main point of my answer is that line profiling is essential to figure out where the slow parts of your code are, be sure to use more than simple timing commands when you are optimizing...but there are certainly times where simple timing is useful, and `timeit` is a module engineered for that task.
- You should factor your code into smaller functions that each accomplish a task.  For example, one function could be generating a list of filenames to parse.  Another function could parse the data and return a dataframe, and a third could find the frequencies.

In the end, it's tough to know what your original speed comparison means.  If your original Python implementation of this script is based off of a direct translation from R, then it probably means that Pandas sucks *at filling dataframes by row*.  But even if that is true, its unclear if Pandas is "slower" than R, because being aware of the row-by-row limitation, you should be able to easily work around it in almost every forseeable use case.  (Can anyone think of an example where filling a dataframe row by row is essential and it can't be done any other way?)

Thanks for asking a fun question!

Here's all the code I used.

---

```
import os
import re
from datetime import datetime

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from glob import glob

# unicode file parsing support in Python 2.x
import codecs

# get unescape to work in Python 2.x
import HTMLParser
unescape = HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape

# line profiling
%load_ext line_profiler
import timeit
```

---

```
def run_code():

    start_time = datetime.now()

    # Create empty dataframe with correct column names
    column_names = ["fileName", "component", "precedingWord", "node", "leftContext", "sentence" ]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((0, len(column_names))), columns=column_names)

    # Create correct path where to fetch files
    subdir = "rawdata"
    path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), subdir))

    # "Cache" regex
    # See http://stackoverflow.com/q/452104/1150683
    p_filename = re.compile(r"[./\\]")

    p_sentence = re.compile(r"<sentence>(.*?)</sentence>")
    p_typography = re.compile(r" (?:(?=[.,:;?!) ])|(?<=\( ))")
    p_non_graph = re.compile(r"[^\x21-\x7E\s]")
    p_quote = re.compile(r"\"")
    p_ellipsis = re.compile(r"\.{3}(?=[^ ])")

    p_last_word = re.compile(r"^.*\b(?<!-)(\w+(?:-\w+)*)[^\w]*$", re.U)

    # Loop files in folder
    filenames = [name for name in os.listdir(path) if re.match('.*[.]lst', name)]

    for filename in filenames:
        with codecs.open('rawdata/' + filename, 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            [n, c] = p_filename.split(filename.lower())[-3:-1]
            fn = ".".join([n, c])
            for line in f:
                uline = unicode(line)
                s = p_sentence.search(unescape(uline)).group(1)
                s = s.lower()
                s = p_typography.sub("", s)
                s = p_non_graph.sub("", s)
                s = p_quote.sub("'", s)
                s = p_ellipsis.sub("... ", s)

                if n in re.split(r"[ :?.,]", s):
                    lc = re.split(r"(^| )" + n + "( |[!\",.:;?})\]])", s)[0]

                    pw = p_last_word.sub("\\1", lc)

                    df = df.append([dict(fileName=fn, component=c, 
                                       precedingWord=pw, node=n, 
                                       leftContext=lc, sentence=s)])
                continue

    # Reset indices
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    # Export dataset
    df.to_csv("dataset/py-dataset.csv", sep="\t", encoding="utf-8")

    # Let's make a frequency list
    # Create new dataframe

    # Define neuter and non_neuter
    neuter = ["het"]
    non_neuter = ["de"]

    # Create crosstab
    df.loc[df.precedingWord.isin(neuter), "gender"] = "neuter"
    df.loc[df.precedingWord.isin(non_neuter), "gender"] = "non_neuter"
    df.loc[df.precedingWord.isin(neuter + non_neuter) == 0, "gender"] = "rest"

    freqDf = pd.crosstab(df.node, df.gender)

    freqDf.to_csv("dataset/py-frequencies.csv", sep="\t", encoding="utf-8")

    # How long has the script been running?
    time_difference = datetime.now() - start_time
    print("Time difference of", time_difference)
    return
```

---

```
%lprun -f run_code run_code()
```

---

In IPython the result of the line profiler is displayed in a pseudo-popup "help" window.  Here it is:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 25.6168 s
File: <ipython-input-5-b8823da4f6a5>
Function: run_code at line 1

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     1                                           def run_code():
     2                                           
     3         1           10     10.0      0.0      start_time = datetime.now()
     4                                           
     5                                               # Create empty dataframe with correct column names
     6         1            2      2.0      0.0      column_names = ["fileName", "component", "precedingWord", "node", "leftContext", "sentence" ]
     7         1          384    384.0      0.0      df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((0, len(column_names))), columns=column_names)
     8                                           
     9                                               # Create correct path where to fetch files
    10         1            2      2.0      0.0      subdir = "rawdata"
    11         1          119    119.0      0.0      path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), subdir))
    12                                           
    13                                               # "Cache" regex
    14                                               # See http://stackoverflow.com/q/452104/1150683
    15         1          265    265.0      0.0      p_filename = re.compile(r"[./\\]")
    16                                           
    17         1          628    628.0      0.0      p_sentence = re.compile(r"<sentence>(.*?)</sentence>")
    18         1          697    697.0      0.0      p_typography = re.compile(r" (?:(?=[.,:;?!) ])|(?<=\( ))")
    19         1          411    411.0      0.0      p_non_graph = re.compile(r"[^\x21-\x7E\s]")
    20         1          128    128.0      0.0      p_quote = re.compile(r"\"")
    21         1          339    339.0      0.0      p_ellipsis = re.compile(r"\.{3}(?=[^ ])")
    22                                           
    23         1         1048   1048.0      0.0      p_last_word = re.compile(r"^.*\b(?<!-)(\w+(?:-\w+)*)[^\w]*$", re.U)
    24                                           
    25                                               # Loop files in folder
    26       108         1122     10.4      0.0      filenames = [name for name in os.listdir(path) if re.match('.*[.]lst', name)]
    27                                               
    28       108          250      2.3      0.0      for filename in filenames:
    29       107         5341     49.9      0.0          with codecs.open('rawdata/' + filename, 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    30       107          867      8.1      0.0              [n, c] = p_filename.split(filename.lower())[-3:-1]
    31       107          277      2.6      0.0              fn = ".".join([n, c])
    32      6607       395024     59.8      1.5              for line in f:
    33      6500        17927      2.8      0.1                  uline = unicode(line)
    34      6500       119436     18.4      0.5                  s = p_sentence.search(unescape(uline)).group(1)
    35      6500        19466      3.0      0.1                  s = s.lower()
    36      6500        53653      8.3      0.2                  s = p_typography.sub("", s)
    37      6500        25654      3.9      0.1                  s = p_non_graph.sub("", s)
    38      6500        17735      2.7      0.1                  s = p_quote.sub("'", s)
    39      6500        31662      4.9      0.1                  s = p_ellipsis.sub("... ", s)
    40                                           
    41      6500       119657     18.4      0.5                  if n in re.split(r"[ :?.,]", s):
    42      5825       117687     20.2      0.5                      lc = re.split(r"(^| )" + n + "( |[!\",.:;?})\]])", s)[0]
    43                                           
    44      5825       133397     22.9      0.5                      pw = p_last_word.sub("\\1", lc)
    45                                           
    46      5825        12575      2.2      0.0                      df = df.append([dict(fileName=fn, component=c, 
    47      5825         8539      1.5      0.0                                         precedingWord=pw, node=n, 
    48      5825     24222087   4158.3     94.6                                         leftContext=lc, sentence=s)])
    49                                                           continue
    50                                               
    51                                               # Reset indices
    52         1          104    104.0      0.0      df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    53                                           
    54                                               # Export dataset
    55         1       293388 293388.0      1.1      df.to_csv("dataset/py-dataset.csv", sep="\t", encoding="utf-8")
    56                                           
    57                                               # Let's make a frequency list
    58                                               # Create new dataframe
    59                                           
    60                                               # Define neuter and non_neuter
    61         1            3      3.0      0.0      neuter = ["het"]
    62         1            1      1.0      0.0      non_neuter = ["de"]
    63                                           
    64                                               # Create crosstab
    65         1         2585   2585.0      0.0      df.loc[df.precedingWord.isin(neuter), "gender"] = "neuter"
    66         1         2125   2125.0      0.0      df.loc[df.precedingWord.isin(non_neuter), "gender"] = "non_neuter"
    67         1         1417   1417.0      0.0      df.loc[df.precedingWord.isin(neuter + non_neuter) == 0, "gender"] = "rest"
    68                                           
    69         1         9666   9666.0      0.0      freqDf = pd.crosstab(df.node, df.gender)
    70                                           
    71         1         1042   1042.0      0.0      freqDf.to_csv("dataset/py-frequencies.csv", sep="\t", encoding="utf-8")
    72                                           
    73                                               # How long has the script been running?
    74         1           20     20.0      0.0      time_difference = datetime.now() - start_time
    75         1           46     46.0      0.0      print("Time difference of", time_difference)
    76         1            1      1.0      0.0      return
```

---

As you can see, building the pandas data frame takes almost all the time.  That suggests a trivial optimization:

---

```
def run_code_faster():

    start_time = datetime.now()

    # Create empty dataframe with correct column names
    column_names = ["fileName", "component", "precedingWord", "node", "leftContext", "sentence" ]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((0, len(column_names))), columns=column_names)

    # Create correct path where to fetch files
    subdir = "rawdata"
    path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), subdir))

    # "Cache" regex
    # See http://stackoverflow.com/q/452104/1150683
    p_filename = re.compile(r"[./\\]")

    p_sentence = re.compile(r"<sentence>(.*?)</sentence>")
    p_typography = re.compile(r" (?:(?=[.,:;?!) ])|(?<=\( ))")
    p_non_graph = re.compile(r"[^\x21-\x7E\s]")
    p_quote = re.compile(r"\"")
    p_ellipsis = re.compile(r"\.{3}(?=[^ ])")

    p_last_word = re.compile(r"^.*\b(?<!-)(\w+(?:-\w+)*)[^\w]*$", re.U)

    # Loop files in folder
    filenames = [name for name in os.listdir(path) if re.match('.*[.]lst', name)]

    fn_list = []
    c_list = []
    pw_list = []
    n_list = []
    lc_list = []
    s_list = []

    for filename in filenames:
        with codecs.open('rawdata/' + filename, 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            [n, c] = p_filename.split(filename.lower())[-3:-1]
            fn = ".".join([n, c])
            for line in f:
                uline = unicode(line)
                s = p_sentence.search(unescape(uline)).group(1)
                s = s.lower()
                s = p_typography.sub("", s)
                s = p_non_graph.sub("", s)
                s = p_quote.sub("'", s)
                s = p_ellipsis.sub("... ", s)

                if n in re.split(r"[ :?.,]", s):
                    lc = re.split(r"(^| )" + n + "( |[!\",.:;?})\]])", s)[0]

                    pw = p_last_word.sub("\\1", lc)

#                     df = df.append([dict(fileName=fn, component=c, 
#                                        precedingWord=pw, node=n, 
#                                        leftContext=lc, sentence=s)])
                    fn_list.append(fn)
                    c_list.append(c)
                    pw_list.append(pw)
                    n_list.append(n)
                    lc_list.append(lc)
                    s_list.append(s)
                continue
    # Assign data frame
    df['fileName'] = fn_list
    df['component'] = c_list
    df['precedingWord'] = pw_list
    df['node'] = n_list
    df['leftContext'] = lc_list
    df['sentence'] = s_list

    # Reset indices
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    # Export dataset
    df.to_csv("dataset/py-dataset.csv", sep="\t", encoding="utf-8")

    # Let's make a frequency list
    # Create new dataframe

    # Define neuter and non_neuter
    neuter = ["het"]
    non_neuter = ["de"]

    # Create crosstab
    df.loc[df.precedingWord.isin(neuter), "gender"] = "neuter"
    df.loc[df.precedingWord.isin(non_neuter), "gender"] = "non_neuter"
    df.loc[df.precedingWord.isin(neuter + non_neuter) == 0, "gender"] = "rest"

    freqDf = pd.crosstab(df.node, df.gender)

    freqDf.to_csv("dataset/py-frequencies.csv", sep="\t", encoding="utf-8")

    # How long has the script been running?
    time_difference = datetime.now() - start_time
    print("Time difference of", time_difference)
    return
```

---

```
%lprun -f run_code_faster run_code_faster()
```

---

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 1.21669 s
File: <ipython-input-2-6ca852e32327>
Function: run_code_faster at line 1

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     1                                           def run_code_faster():
     2                                           
     3         1           10     10.0      0.0      start_time = datetime.now()
     4                                           
     5                                               # Create empty dataframe with correct column names
     6         1            2      2.0      0.0      column_names = ["fileName", "component", "precedingWord", "node", "leftContext", "sentence" ]
     7         1          412    412.0      0.0      df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.zeros((0, len(column_names))), columns=column_names)
     8                                           
     9                                               # Create correct path where to fetch files
    10         1            1      1.0      0.0      subdir = "rawdata"
    11         1          120    120.0      0.0      path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), subdir))
    12                                           
    13                                               # "Cache" regex
    14                                               # See http://stackoverflow.com/q/452104/1150683
    15         1           11     11.0      0.0      p_filename = re.compile(r"[./\\]")
    16                                           
    17         1            6      6.0      0.0      p_sentence = re.compile(r"<sentence>(.*?)</sentence>")
    18         1           12     12.0      0.0      p_typography = re.compile(r" (?:(?=[.,:;?!) ])|(?<=\( ))")
    19         1            6      6.0      0.0      p_non_graph = re.compile(r"[^\x21-\x7E\s]")
    20         1            5      5.0      0.0      p_quote = re.compile(r"\"")
    21         1            5      5.0      0.0      p_ellipsis = re.compile(r"\.{3}(?=[^ ])")
    22                                           
    23         1            6      6.0      0.0      p_last_word = re.compile(r"^.*\b(?<!-)(\w+(?:-\w+)*)[^\w]*$", re.U)
    24                                           
    25                                               # Loop files in folder
    26       108          964      8.9      0.1      filenames = [name for name in os.listdir(path) if re.match('.*[.]lst', name)]
    27                                               
    28         1            1      1.0      0.0      fn_list = []
    29         1            1      1.0      0.0      c_list = []
    30         1            1      1.0      0.0      pw_list = []
    31         1            2      2.0      0.0      n_list = []
    32         1            2      2.0      0.0      lc_list = []
    33         1            2      2.0      0.0      s_list = []
    34                                               
    35       108          286      2.6      0.0      for filename in filenames:
    36       107         6811     63.7      0.6          with codecs.open('rawdata/' + filename, 'r+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    37       107         1026      9.6      0.1              [n, c] = p_filename.split(filename.lower())[-3:-1]
    38       107          314      2.9      0.0              fn = ".".join([n, c])
    39      6607       311585     47.2     25.6              for line in f:
    40      6500        15037      2.3      1.2                  uline = unicode(line)
    41      6500        94829     14.6      7.8                  s = p_sentence.search(unescape(uline)).group(1)
    42      6500        17369      2.7      1.4                  s = s.lower()
    43      6500        42040      6.5      3.5                  s = p_typography.sub("", s)
    44      6500        23783      3.7      2.0                  s = p_non_graph.sub("", s)
    45      6500        16132      2.5      1.3                  s = p_quote.sub("'", s)
    46      6500        31856      4.9      2.6                  s = p_ellipsis.sub("... ", s)
    47                                           
    48      6500       101812     15.7      8.4                  if n in re.split(r"[ :?.,]", s):
    49      5825        71344     12.2      5.9                      lc = re.split(r"(^| )" + n + "( |[!\",.:;?})\]])", s)[0]
    50                                           
    51      5825       103504     17.8      8.5                      pw = p_last_word.sub("\\1", lc)
    52                                           
    53                                           #                     df = df.append([dict(fileName=fn, component=c, 
    54                                           #                                        precedingWord=pw, node=n, 
    55                                           #                                        leftContext=lc, sentence=s)])
    56      5825        11036      1.9      0.9                      fn_list.append(fn)
    57      5825         9798      1.7      0.8                      c_list.append(c)
    58      5825         9587      1.6      0.8                      pw_list.append(pw)
    59      5825         9642      1.7      0.8                      n_list.append(n)
    60      5825         9516      1.6      0.8                      lc_list.append(lc)
    61      5825         9390      1.6      0.8                      s_list.append(s)
    62                                                           continue
    63                                               # Assign data frame
    64         1         1448   1448.0      0.1      df['fileName'] = fn_list
    65         1          517    517.0      0.0      df['component'] = c_list
    66         1          532    532.0      0.0      df['precedingWord'] = pw_list
    67         1          493    493.0      0.0      df['node'] = n_list
    68         1          511    511.0      0.0      df['leftContext'] = lc_list
    69         1          437    437.0      0.0      df['sentence'] = s_list
    70                                               
    71                                               # Reset indices
    72         1           88     88.0      0.0      df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    73                                           
    74                                               # Export dataset
    75         1       296747 296747.0     24.4      df.to_csv("dataset/py-dataset.csv", sep="\t", encoding="utf-8")
    76                                           
    77                                               # Let's make a frequency list
    78                                               # Create new dataframe
    79                                           
    80                                               # Define neuter and non_neuter
    81         1            3      3.0      0.0      neuter = ["het"]
    82         1            1      1.0      0.0      non_neuter = ["de"]
    83                                           
    84                                               # Create crosstab
    85         1         3878   3878.0      0.3      df.loc[df.precedingWord.isin(neuter), "gender"] = "neuter"
    86         1         1871   1871.0      0.2      df.loc[df.precedingWord.isin(non_neuter), "gender"] = "non_neuter"
    87         1         1405   1405.0      0.1      df.loc[df.precedingWord.isin(neuter + non_neuter) == 0, "gender"] = "rest"
    88                                           
    89         1         9203   9203.0      0.8      freqDf = pd.crosstab(df.node, df.gender)
    90                                           
    91         1         1234   1234.0      0.1      freqDf.to_csv("dataset/py-frequencies.csv", sep="\t", encoding="utf-8")
    92                                           
    93                                               # How long has the script been running?
    94         1           12     12.0      0.0      time_difference = datetime.now() - start_time
    95         1           43     43.0      0.0      print("Time difference of", time_difference)
    96         1            1      1.0      0.0      return
```

---

Comment: What a thorough anwer, thank you for that! +1 I ran your code and, indeed, it is unbelievably fast. And a very "easy" solution. Should've thought about that myself. On all my data it runs in 5 minutes - whereas the R script needs 40 minutes. Two question though: why do we need `return` at the end of the function? And how should I use timeit? In other words, how can I use it from within Python and get an output when the script has finished running that is neatly formatted in mm:ss? I googled it, but got nothing.

Comment: The `return` is good form for ending functions, even if you aren't returning any values.  It makes it easier for readers of the code to see when your function definition is over.  Also, If you want to adapt the `run_code()` function to actually return your pandas dataframe, then you could end with `return df` or similar.

Comment: I think the [`timeit` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) are pretty informative on how to use it from the command line and from a Python interpreter.  The main purpose of `timeit` is to avoid pitfalls from variable time from system overhead distorting your timing measurements.  If your code takes 5 minutes to run, `datetime` is fine, but you'll have a hard time interpreting `datetime` result if you are timing a codeblock that takes 5 microseconds to run.  Results will be highly variable and non-repeatable, `timeit` fixes that.

Comment: Would this be a good idea of seperating in functions?: http://pastebin.com/hgR55ajZ I can't put the initial part in a function because of the scope of the imported variables.

Comment: Hi Bram, good question!  So good, in fact, that if you don't mind, it should really be a brand new question on Code Review.  From a quick look it doesn't seem like you are `return`ing values from any of the functions -- if you are relying on global scope, that's bad.  Future Code Review answerers can help explain why.

Comment: I posted it as [a new question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/101838/21093). I'll award you the bounty a day before it expires. Who knows, maybe some one else can write an even better performing script!

Answer (score 3):

## Gorillas vs. Sharks:

You can't simply compare [r](/questions/tagged/r) and [python](/questions/tagged/python), they're like, well, Gorillas and Sharks.

It's not as simple as: which is better?

And, it's often not the language that's better, but the quality of the code!

---

## Possible things that could be slowing execution:

#### *Things not specific to you*:

- Beginner's language abuse: as a self-confessed beginner, you may be using the functions or functionality of Python incorrectly.
- Library abuse: Some libraries aren't exactly a walk in the park to use, you may not be using some of the libraries properly.
- Library quality: Assuming library quality is a bit naïve, the actual code behind the library may not be as optimised or good as the other language's implementation.

#### *Things specific to you*:

- Regex: There's many regex being executed, which, is quite a time consuming process, this regex: `(?:(?=[.,:;?!) ])|(?<=\( ))` managed to register 3000 steps for me!

---

`s = s.lower()`, if you're using certain characters in your content, this can have issues.

I'd recommend taking a look over at [How do I do a case insensitive string comparison in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29247821/3296811).

---

> ```
>         if n in re.split(r"[ :?.,]", s):
>             lc = re.split(r"(^| )" + n + "( |[!\",.:;?})\]])", s)[0]
> ```

What is `n`, `re`, `lc` or `s`? Your variable names are unclear and confusing to read.

Comment: I think the variable names are quite clear. Take a look at the .append function, you'll see that the letters are abbreviations of the column names. I know you can't simply compare two languages that way, each has its merits. But in this specific case it seemed to me that Python ought to be faster in data crunching. My current Python code works, so there's no issue with `lower()` for me. As I stated I'm indeed a beginner, and I'm here to look for help. If someone could help me using some higher hierarchy functions as proposed on SO (imap, ifilter...) **and explaining them** that would be great.