# Generating frequency tables based on CSV dataset, in R

Tags: performance, csv, r

As a follow-up to [this question concerning Python](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101648/generating-frequency-tables-based-on-csv-dataset) I present you with the exact same thing - for R.

Initially I started with R. However, it takes 44 minutes to run when unleashed on all my data. I then looked for an alternative. I read about Python and got advised to use pandas by a colleague. So I set out on an adventure. At first I was disappointed because my script was actually slower than my R script. Luckily I got some great help which reduced the execution time of my Python script drastically. When running it against all my data it takes ... 4 minutes (!) to execute. That's more than 11x faster than the R script. So I thought to myself, if the good folk at CR can bring the speed of my scripts up to such a good time, then maybe they can do something similar for my R script.

Eventually I'll be going with Python because I'm more familiar with the methods used there, so basically this is **a contest** for you guys. Can you optimise the R script below so that it finishes more quickly than its Python equivalent in the answer provided above?

Here's a copy-paste of what my script is actually doing:

---

I am working on a project which crunches plain text files (`.lst`). *Data to test the script can be downloaded [here](http://bramvanroy.be/files/testdata.zip)*.

The name of the file names (`fileName`) are important because I'll extract `node` (e.g. `abessijn`) and `component` (e.g. `WR-P-E-A`) from them into a dataframe.

Examples:

> ```
> abessijn.WR-P-E-A.lst
> A-bom.WR-P-E-A.lst
> acroniem.WR-P-E-C.lst
> acroniem.WR-P-E-G.lst
> adapter.WR-P-E-A.lst
> adapter.WR-P-E-C.lst
> adapter.WR-P-E-G.lst
> ```

Each file consists of one or more line. Each line consists of a sentence (inside `<sentence>` tags).

Example (`abessijn.WR-P-E-A.lst`):

```
<sentence>Vooral mijn abessijn ruikt heerlijk kruidig .. : ) )</sentence>
<sentence>Mijn abessijn denkt daar heel anders over .. : ) ) Maar mijn kinderen richt ik ook niet af , zit niet in mijn bloed .</sentence>
```

From each line I extract the sentence, do some small modifications to it, and call it `sentence`. Up next is an element called `leftContext`, which takes the first part of the split between `node` (e.g. `abessijn`) and the sentence it came from. Finally, from `leftContext` I get `precedingWord`, which is the word preceding `node` in `sentence`, or the right most word in `leftContext` (with some limitations such as the option of a compound formed with a hyphen).

Example:

```
ID | filename             | node | component | precedingWord      | leftContext                               |  sentence
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    adapter.WR-P-P-F.lst  adapter  WR-P-P-F   aanpassingseenheid  Een aanpassingseenheid (                      Een aanpassingseenheid ( adapter ) , 
2    adapter.WR-P-P-F.lst  adapter  WR-P-P-F   toestel             Het toestel (                                 Het toestel ( adapter ) draagt zorg voor de overbrenging van gegevens
3    adapter.WR-P-P-F.lst  adapter  WR-P-P-F   de                  de aansluiting tussen de sensor en de         de aansluiting tussen de sensor en de adapter , 
4    airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst   airbag   WS-U-E-A   den                 ja voor den                                   ja voor den airbag op te pompen eh :p
5    airbag.WS-U-E-A.lst   airbag   WS-U-E-A   ne                  Dobby , als ze valt heeft ze dan wel al ne    Dobby , als ze valt heeft ze dan wel al ne airbag hee
```

That dataframe is exported as `dataset.csv`.

After that, the intention of my project comes at hand: I create a frequency table that takes `node` and `precedingWord` into account. From a variable I define `neuter` and `non_neuter`, e.g (in Python):

```
neuter = ["het", "Het"]
non_neuter = ["de","De"]
```

and a rest category `unspecified`. When `precedingWord` is an item from the list, assign it to the variable. Example of a frequency table output:

> ```
> node    |   neuter   | nonNeuter   | unspecified
> -------------------------------------------------
> A-bom       0          4             2
> acroniem    3          0             2
> act         3          2             1
> ```

The frequency list is exported as `frequencies.csv`.

---

My R script looks like this:

```r
# ---
# STEP 0: Preparations
    start_time <- Sys.time()
  ## 1. Set working directory in R
    setwd("C:/User/Desktop/testdata")

  ## 2. Load required library/libraries
    library(dplyr)
    library(stringi)

  ## 3. Create directory where we'll save our dataset(s)
    dir.create("../R/dataset", showWarnings = FALSE)
    Rprof("../R/dataset/profiling.out", line.profiling=TRUE)

# ---
# STEP 1: Loop through files, get data from the file_name

    ## 1. Create first dataframe, based on file_name of all files
    files <- list.files(pattern="*.lst", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
    d <- data.frame(file_name = stri_trans_tolower(unname(sapply(files, basename))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

    ## 2. Create additional columns (word & component) based on file_name
    file_nameSplit <- stri_split_fixed(d$file_name, ".")
    d$node <- sapply(file_nameSplit, "[", 1)
    d$component <- sapply(file_nameSplit, "[", 2)
    d$file_name <- paste(d$node, d$component, sep=".")

# ---
# STEP 2: Loop through files again, but now also through its contents
# In other words: get the sentences

    ## 1. Create second set which is an rbind of multiple frames
    ## One two-column data.frame per file
    ## First column is file_name, second column is data from each file
    e <- do.call(rbind, lapply(files, function(x) {
        data.frame(file_name = stri_trans_tolower(unname(sapply(x, basename))), sentence = readLines(x, encoding="UTF-8"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    }))

    # Before doing anything else we got to
    # get rid of some characters we can't use such as ³ and ¾
    e$sentence <- stri_replace_all_regex(e$sentence, "[^[:graph:]\\s]", "")
    # Only NOW we can lower-case it
    e$sentence <- stri_trans_tolower(e$sentence)

    ## 2. Clean file_name
     e$file_name <- stri_replace_first_regex(e$file_name, "(.*)\\.lst$", "$1")

    ## 3. Get the sentence and clean
    e$sentence <- stri_replace_all_regex(e$sentence, ".*?<sentence>(.*?)</sentence>", "$1")
        # Remove floating space before/after punctuation
        e$sentence <- stri_replace_all_regex(e$sentence, "\\s(?:(?=[.,:;?!) ])|(?<=\\( ))", "")
        # Add space after triple dots ...
        e$sentence <- stri_replace_all_regex(e$sentence, "\\.{3}(?=[^\\s])", "... ")

      # Transform HTML entities into characters
      # It is unfortunate that there's no easier way to do this
      # E.g. Python provides the HTML package which can unescape (decode) HTML
      # characters
          e$sentence <- stri_replace_all_fixed(e$sentence, "&apos;", "'")
          e$sentence <- stri_replace_all_fixed(e$sentence, "&amp;", "&")
        # Avoid R from wrongly interpreting ", so replace by single quotes
          e$sentence <- stri_replace_all_regex(e$sentence, "&quot;|\"", "'")


# ---
# STEP 3:
# Create final dataframe

  ## 1. Merge d and e by common column name file_name
    df <- merge(d, e, by="file_name", all=TRUE)

  ## 2. Make sure that only those sentences in which df$node is present in df$sentence are taken into account
    matchFunction <- function(x, y) any(x == y)
    matchedFrame <- with(df, mapply(matchFunction, node, stri_split_regex(sentence, "[ :?.,]")))
    df <- df[matchedFrame, ]

  ## 3. Create left_context based on the split of the word and the sentence
    # Use paste0 to make sure we are looking for the node, not a compound
    # node can only be preceded by a space, but can be followed by punctuation as well
    contexts <- stri_split_regex(df$sentence, paste0("(^| )", df$node, "( |[!\",.:;?})\\]])"))
    df$left_context <- sapply(contexts, `[`, 1)

  ## 4. Get the word preceding the node
    df$preceding_word <- stri_replace_all_regex(df$left_context, "^.*\\b(?<!-)(\\w+(?:-\\w+)*)[^\\w]*$","$1")

  ## 5. Improve readability by sorting columns
    df <- df[c("file_name", "component", "preceding_word", "node", "left_context", "sentence")]

  ## 6. Write dataset to dataset dir
    # write.csv2(df,"../R/dataset/r-dataset.csv")


# ---
# STEP 4:
# Create dataset with frequencies

  ## 1. Define neuter and nonNeuter classes
    neuter <- c("het")
    non.neuter<- c("de")

  ## 2. Mutate df to fit into usable frame
    freq <- mutate(df, gender = ifelse(!df$preceding_word %in% c(neuter, non.neuter), "unspecified",
      ifelse(df$preceding_word %in% neuter, "neuter", "non_neuter")))

  ## 3. Transform into table, but still usable as data frame (i.e. matrix)
  ## Also add column name "node"
    freqTable <- table(freq$node, freq$gender) %>%
      as.data.frame.matrix %>%
      mutate(node = row.names(.))

  ## 4. Small adjustements
    freqTable <- freqTable[,c(4,1:3)]

  ## 5. Write dataset to dataset dir
    write.csv2(freqTable,"../R/dataset/r-frequencies.csv")


    diff <- Sys.time() - start_time # calculate difference
    print(diff) # print in nice format
    Rprof(NULL)
    summaryRprof("../R/dataset/profiling.out")
```

I swapped out the mclm library for a native write.csv2. Also, note that the testdata is only a quick way to test the script and its output. Actual data consists of 16.500 files, consisting of between 1 to 100s of lines!

I also ran some basic profiling. (See script above.) Here are the results. I will now run the profiling on all the data, maybe there's a difference.

> ```
> $by.self
>                   self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
> ".Call"                0.48     60.0       0.50      62.5
> "readLines"            0.08     10.0       0.10      12.5
> "lapply"               0.02      2.5       0.14      17.5
> "[.data.frame"         0.02      2.5       0.04       5.0
> "rbind"                0.02      2.5       0.04       5.0
> ".row_names_info"      0.02      2.5       0.02       2.5
> "=="                   0.02      2.5       0.02       2.5
> "deparse"              0.02      2.5       0.02       2.5
> "file"                 0.02      2.5       0.02       2.5
> "gsub"                 0.02      2.5       0.02       2.5
> "ifelse"               0.02      2.5       0.02       2.5
> "match"                0.02      2.5       0.02       2.5
> "paste0"               0.02      2.5       0.02       2.5
> "sort.list"            0.02      2.5       0.02       2.5
>
> $by.total
>                            total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
> ".Call"                          0.50      62.5      0.48     60.0
> "stri_replace_all_regex"         0.24      30.0      0.00      0.0
> "stri_split_regex"               0.22      27.5      0.00      0.0
> "do.call"                        0.16      20.0      0.00      0.0
> "lapply"                         0.14      17.5      0.02      2.5
> "data.frame"                     0.14      17.5      0.00      0.0
> "FUN"                            0.14      17.5      0.00      0.0
> "eval"                           0.12      15.0      0.00      0.0
> "readLines"                      0.10      12.5      0.08     10.0
> "<Anonymous>"                    0.06       7.5      0.00      0.0
> "mapply"                         0.06       7.5      0.00      0.0
> "with"                           0.06       7.5      0.00      0.0
> "with.default"                   0.06       7.5      0.00      0.0
> "[.data.frame"                   0.04       5.0      0.02      2.5
> "rbind"                          0.04       5.0      0.02      2.5
> "["                              0.04       5.0      0.00      0.0
> "as.data.frame"                  0.04       5.0      0.00      0.0
> "merge"                          0.04       5.0      0.00      0.0
> "merge.data.frame"               0.04       5.0      0.00      0.0
> "stri_trans_tolower"             0.04       5.0      0.00      0.0
> ".row_names_info"                0.02       2.5      0.02      2.5
> "=="                             0.02       2.5      0.02      2.5
> "deparse"                        0.02       2.5      0.02      2.5
> "file"                           0.02       2.5      0.02      2.5
> "gsub"                           0.02       2.5      0.02      2.5
> "ifelse"                         0.02       2.5      0.02      2.5
> "match"                          0.02       2.5      0.02      2.5
> "paste0"                         0.02       2.5      0.02      2.5
> "sort.list"                      0.02       2.5      0.02      2.5
> "%>%"                            0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> "as.data.frame.character"        0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> "doTryCatch"                     0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> "eval.parent"                    0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> "evalq"                          0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> "factor"                         0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> "mutate"                         0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> "mutate_"                        0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> "mutate_.data.frame"             0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> "mutate_.tbl_df"                 0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> "mutate_impl"                    0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> "paste"                          0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> "sapply"                         0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> "stri_replace_first_regex"       0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> "table"                          0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> "tryCatch"                       0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> "tryCatchList"                   0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> "tryCatchOne"                    0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> "unname"                         0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> "vapply"                         0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> "write.csv2"                     0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> "write.table"                    0.02       2.5      0.00      0.0
> ```

And when profiling the script when it runs all my data:

> ```
> $by.self
>                           self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
> "rbind"                     1905.88    79.16    1908.12     79.25
> ".Call"                      256.76    10.66     260.04     10.80
> "file"                        84.04     3.49      84.06      3.49
> "readLines"                   51.38     2.13     135.92      5.65
> "mapply"                      17.84     0.74      61.46      2.55
> "data.frame"                  16.00     0.66     160.12      6.65
> "sort.list"                   13.72     0.57      13.78      0.57
> "<Anonymous>"                 12.72     0.53    1926.64     80.02
> "lapply"                      11.34     0.47     156.58      6.50
> "make.unique"                  7.38     0.31      10.20      0.42
> "=="                           4.46     0.19       4.46      0.19
> "ifelse"                       2.92     0.12       3.28      0.14
> "as.character"                 2.82     0.12       2.82      0.12
> "unique.default"               2.52     0.10       2.54      0.11
> "unlist"                       2.28     0.09       2.38      0.10
> "match"                        2.16     0.09       3.06      0.13
> "anyDuplicated.default"        1.68     0.07       1.68      0.07
> "any"                          1.44     0.06       1.44      0.06
> "[.data.frame"                 1.38     0.06      25.98      1.08
> "paste0"                       1.10     0.05       1.10      0.05
> ".deparseOpts"                 0.82     0.03       1.66      0.07
> "deparse"                      0.68     0.03       2.98      0.12
> "pmatch"                       0.50     0.02       0.52      0.02
> "[["                           0.48     0.02       1.24      0.05
> "is.factor"                    0.42     0.02       0.42      0.02
> "as.data.frame"                0.36     0.01       6.94      0.29
> "integer"                      0.34     0.01       0.34      0.01
> "FUN"                          0.30     0.01     145.80      6.06
> "match.fun"                    0.30     0.01       0.30      0.01
> "order"                        0.26     0.01       0.42      0.02
> "close.connection"             0.26     0.01       0.26      0.01
> "merge.data.frame"             0.22     0.01      40.20      1.67
> "close"                        0.22     0.01       0.48      0.02
> "as.list"                      0.20     0.01       0.26      0.01
> "lengths"                      0.20     0.01       0.20      0.01
> "unique"                       0.16     0.01       2.88      0.12
> "names"                        0.16     0.01       0.16      0.01
> "as.data.frame.vector"         0.14     0.01       0.20      0.01
> "%in%"                         0.12     0.00       2.58      0.11
> "table"                        0.12     0.00       2.24      0.09
> "make.names"                   0.10     0.00       0.62      0.03
> "Make.row.names"               0.10     0.00       0.12      0.00
> "list.files"                   0.10     0.00       0.10      0.00
> "unclass"                      0.10     0.00       0.10      0.00
> "simplify2array"               0.08     0.00       3.24      0.13
> "attr"                         0.08     0.00       0.08      0.00
> "sum"                          0.08     0.00       0.08      0.00
> "sapply"                       0.06     0.00      13.22      0.55
> "as.data.frame.character"      0.06     0.00       3.28      0.14
> "[[.data.frame"                0.06     0.00       0.76      0.03
> ".row_names_info"              0.06     0.00       0.06      0.00
> "as.list.default"              0.06     0.00       0.06      0.00
> "length"                       0.06     0.00       0.06      0.00
> "mode"                         0.04     0.00       1.24      0.05
> "inDL"                         0.04     0.00       0.04      0.00
> "is.expression"                0.04     0.00       0.04      0.00
> "is.matrix"                    0.04     0.00       0.04      0.00
> "lazyLoadDBfetch"              0.04     0.00       0.04      0.00
> "sys.call"                     0.04     0.00       0.04      0.00
> "do.call"                      0.02     0.00    2053.84     85.30
> "stri_trans_tolower"           0.02     0.00      18.94      0.79
> "factor"                       0.02     0.00       2.10      0.09
> "!"                            0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
> ".External2"                   0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
> ".set_row_names"               0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
> ".subset2"                     0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
> "abs"                          0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
> "anyNA"                        0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
> "as.integer"                   0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
> "c"                            0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
> "find.package"                 0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
> "force"                        0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
> "getOption"                    0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
> "is.data.frame"                0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
> "is.na"                        0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
> "list"                         0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
> "nzchar"                       0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
> "paste"                        0.02     0.00       0.02      0.00
>
> $by.total
>                            total.time total.pct self.time self.pct
> "do.call"                     2053.84     85.30      0.02     0.00
> "<Anonymous>"                 1926.64     80.02     12.72     0.53
> "rbind"                       1908.12     79.25   1905.88    79.16
> ".Call"                        260.04     10.80    256.76    10.66
> "data.frame"                   160.12      6.65     16.00     0.66
> "lapply"                       156.58      6.50     11.34     0.47
> "FUN"                          145.80      6.06      0.30     0.01
> "readLines"                    135.92      5.65     51.38     2.13
> "stri_replace_all_regex"       121.96      5.07      0.00     0.00
> "stri_split_regex"             110.08      4.57      0.00     0.00
> "file"                          84.06      3.49     84.04     3.49
> "eval"                          67.02      2.78      0.00     0.00
> "mapply"                        61.46      2.55     17.84     0.74
> "with"                          61.46      2.55      0.00     0.00
> "with.default"                  61.46      2.55      0.00     0.00
> "merge"                         40.22      1.67      0.00     0.00
> "merge.data.frame"              40.20      1.67      0.22     0.01
> "[.data.frame"                  25.98      1.08      1.38     0.06
> "["                             25.98      1.08      0.00     0.00
> "stri_trans_tolower"            18.94      0.79      0.02     0.00
> "cbind"                         14.32      0.59      0.00     0.00
> "sort.list"                     13.78      0.57     13.72     0.57
> "sapply"                        13.22      0.55      0.06     0.00
> "make.unique"                   10.20      0.42      7.38     0.31
> "as.data.frame"                  6.94      0.29      0.36     0.01
> "stri_replace_first_regex"       5.48      0.23      0.00     0.00
> "=="                             4.46      0.19      4.46     0.19
> "stri_replace_all_fixed"         3.48      0.14      0.00     0.00
> "mutate"                         3.38      0.14      0.00     0.00
> "mutate_"                        3.38      0.14      0.00     0.00
> "mutate_.data.frame"             3.38      0.14      0.00     0.00
> "doTryCatch"                     3.34      0.14      0.00     0.00
> "tryCatch"                       3.34      0.14      0.00     0.00
> "tryCatchList"                   3.34      0.14      0.00     0.00
> "tryCatchOne"                    3.34      0.14      0.00     0.00
> "ifelse"                         3.28      0.14      2.92     0.12
> "as.data.frame.character"        3.28      0.14      0.06     0.00
> "evalq"                          3.28      0.14      0.00     0.00
> "mutate_.tbl_df"                 3.28      0.14      0.00     0.00
> "mutate_impl"                    3.28      0.14      0.00     0.00
> "simplify2array"                 3.24      0.13      0.08     0.00
> "match"                          3.06      0.13      2.16     0.09
> "deparse"                        2.98      0.12      0.68     0.03
> "unique"                         2.88      0.12      0.16     0.01
> "as.character"                   2.82      0.12      2.82     0.12
> "%in%"                           2.58      0.11      0.12     0.00
> "unique.default"                 2.54      0.11      2.52     0.10
> "unlist"                         2.38      0.10      2.28     0.09
> "%>%"                            2.26      0.09      0.00     0.00
> "table"                          2.24      0.09      0.12     0.00
> "factor"                         2.10      0.09      0.02     0.00
> "unname"                         2.06      0.09      0.00     0.00
> "anyDuplicated.default"          1.68      0.07      1.68     0.07
> "anyDuplicated"                  1.68      0.07      0.00     0.00
> ".deparseOpts"                   1.66      0.07      0.82     0.03
> "any"                            1.44      0.06      1.44     0.06
> "[["                             1.24      0.05      0.48     0.02
> "mode"                           1.24      0.05      0.04     0.00
> "paste0"                         1.10      0.05      1.10     0.05
> "[[.data.frame"                  0.76      0.03      0.06     0.00
> "make.names"                     0.62      0.03      0.10     0.00
> "pmatch"                         0.52      0.02      0.50     0.02
> "close"                          0.48      0.02      0.22     0.01
> "is.factor"                      0.42      0.02      0.42     0.02
> "order"                          0.42      0.02      0.26     0.01
> "data.row.names"                 0.40      0.02      0.00     0.00
> "integer"                        0.34      0.01      0.34     0.01
> "match.fun"                      0.30      0.01      0.30     0.01
> "close.connection"               0.26      0.01      0.26     0.01
> "as.list"                        0.26      0.01      0.20     0.01
> "lengths"                        0.20      0.01      0.20     0.01
> "as.data.frame.vector"           0.20      0.01      0.14     0.01
> "names"                          0.16      0.01      0.16     0.01
> "Make.row.names"                 0.12      0.00      0.10     0.00
> "list.files"                     0.10      0.00      0.10     0.00
> "unclass"                        0.10      0.00      0.10     0.00
> "attr"                           0.08      0.00      0.08     0.00
> "sum"                            0.08      0.00      0.08     0.00
> ".row_names_info"                0.06      0.00      0.06     0.00
> "as.list.default"                0.06      0.00      0.06     0.00
> "length"                         0.06      0.00      0.06     0.00
> "::"                             0.06      0.00      0.00     0.00
> "asNamespace"                    0.06      0.00      0.00     0.00
> "getExportedValue"               0.06      0.00      0.00     0.00
> "getNamespace"                   0.06      0.00      0.00     0.00
> "loadNamespace"                  0.06      0.00      0.00     0.00
> "vapply"                         0.06      0.00      0.00     0.00
> "inDL"                           0.04      0.00      0.04     0.00
> "is.expression"                  0.04      0.00      0.04     0.00
> "is.matrix"                      0.04      0.00      0.04     0.00
> "lazyLoadDBfetch"                0.04      0.00      0.04     0.00
> "sys.call"                       0.04      0.00      0.04     0.00
> "dyn.load"                       0.04      0.00      0.00     0.00
> "library.dynam"                  0.04      0.00      0.00     0.00
> "match.names"                    0.04      0.00      0.00     0.00
> "!"                              0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
> ".External2"                     0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
> ".set_row_names"                 0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
> ".subset2"                       0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
> "abs"                            0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
> "anyNA"                          0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
> "as.integer"                     0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
> "c"                              0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
> "find.package"                   0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
> "force"                          0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
> "getOption"                      0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
> "is.data.frame"                  0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
> "is.na"                          0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
> "list"                           0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
> "nzchar"                         0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
> "paste"                          0.02      0.00      0.02     0.00
> "_fseq"                          0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
> "as.lazy_dots"                   0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
> "eval.parent"                    0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
> "freduce"                        0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
> "tbl_df"                         0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
> "withVisible"                    0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
> "write.csv2"                     0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
> "write.table"                    0.02      0.00      0.00     0.00
> ```

The amount of rows:

> ```
> > nrow(d)
> [1] 16,417
> > nrow(e)
> [1] 3,352,602
> > nrow(df)
> [1] 2,816,442
> > nrow(freqTable)
> [1] 1532
> ```

Comment: 1) where can we find the `mclm` package? Or can we safely assume that `write.dataset` is fast and not the cause of your slow run? 2) Except for `write.dataset`, I was able to run your code on the sample data you provided in the zip and it ran very fast: 1.3 seconds. Your real data must be a lot larger for your code to run for 44 minutes, can you please give more info: number of files, and total number of rows (nrow(e))? 3) Have you done some basic profiling to identify the slow parts of the process?

Comment: Easy to grab SIGNIFICANT improvements: replace `readLines` with `readr::read_lines`, `strsplit` with `stringi::stri_split_regex`, `sub` with `stringi::stri_replace_first_regex`, and `gsub` with `stringi::stri_replace_all_regex`. Making these changes make your code run 15x faster on your sample data. I'll be happy to help more if you can answer some of the questions above, especially 2)

Comment: @flodel I must have done something wrong, but performance hasn't improved significantly when using the stringi package (see my edited code above)

Comment: I think I did something wrong, where I forgot to move the arguments around when switching from sub/gsub to their stringi versions. I had checked that the final output (`freqTable`) were identical though... Can you try to answer my question 2) above? It will really help benchmark your code and see where improvements will be beneficial.

Comment: @flodel I had some more time on my hands this morning so I removed the mclm package, added profiling and other information and updated the script. Please see my edit!

Comment: So apparently, binding your 16k data.frames is the culprit. I'd recommend you use the `rbindlist` function from the `datatable` package. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/19698152/1201032 for a nice comparison of various solutions to your problem.

Comment: Another interesting piece: the profiler results you provided show that `rbind` is not a problem when running on your small data sample. This is why it is always useful that you give all the info about the full data like I was asking. I was a pain for a reason :-) If you'll want us to continue improving the rest of the code, we will need to know the total number `nrow(e)` of rows across all the files.

Comment: @flodel I added the amount of rows for each dataframe!

Comment: @Jamal, could you explain the edit? Why a code tag inside a quote tag?

Comment: I do that with text formatted as code that's not actually code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot!

```
setwd("C:/User/Desktop/testdata")
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)
library(readr)

dir.create("../R/dataset", showWarnings = FALSE)
Rprof("../R/dataset/profiling.out")
files <- list.files(pattern = "[.]lst$", full.names = TRUE)
file.pattern <- "^.*[/](([^.]+)[.]([^.]+))[.]lst$"
d <- data.frame(file_name = tolower(sub(file.pattern, "\\1", files)),
                node      = tolower(sub(file.pattern, "\\2", files)),
                component = tolower(sub(file.pattern, "\\3", files)))
l <- lapply(files, readLines, encoding = "UTF-8")
n <- vapply(l, length, integer(1L))
e <- data.frame(sentence  = unlist(l, use.names = FALSE),
                file_name = rep(d$file_name, n),
                node      = rep(d$node     , n),
                component = rep(d$component, n),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

e$sentence <- stri_replace_all_regex(e$sentence, "[^[:graph:]\\s]", "")
e$sentence <- stri_trans_tolower(e$sentence)
e$sentence <- stri_replace_all_regex(e$sentence, ".*?<sentence>(.*?)</sentence>", "$1")
e$sentence <- stri_replace_all_regex(e$sentence, "\\s(?:(?=[.,:;?!) ])|(?<=\\( ))", "")
e$sentence <- stri_replace_all_regex(e$sentence, "\\.{3}(?=[^\\s])", "... ")
e$sentence <- stri_replace_all_fixed(e$sentence, "&apos;", "'")
e$sentence <- stri_replace_all_fixed(e$sentence, "&amp;", "&")
e$sentence <- stri_replace_all_regex(e$sentence, "&quot;|\"", "'")

is.matched <- with(e, unlist(
   Map(`%in%`, node, stri_split_regex(sentence, "[ :?.,]")),
   use.names = FALSE
))
df <- e[is.matched, ]

contexts <- stri_split_regex(df$sentence, paste0("(^| )", df$node, "( |[!\",.:;?})\\]])"))
df$left_context <- vapply(contexts, `[[`, character(1L), 1L)
df$preceding_word <- stri_replace_all_regex(df$left_context, "^.*\\b(?<!-)(\\w+(?:-\\w+)*)[^\\w]*$","$1")
df <- df[c("file_name", "component", "preceding_word", "node", "left_context", "sentence")]

neuter <- c("het")
non.neuter<- c("de")
df$gender <- ifelse(df$preceding_word %in% c(neuter),     "neuter",
             ifelse(df$preceding_word %in% c(non.neuter), "non_neuter",       
                                                          "unspecified"))
freqTable <- table(df$node, df$gender) %>%
   as.data.frame.matrix %>%
   cbind(node = row.names(.), .)

write.csv2(freqTable,"../R/dataset/r-frequencies.csv", row.names = FALSE)
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof("../R/dataset/profiling.out")
```

What are the improvements?

1. The profiler showed that rbind-ing your 16.5k data.frames was the main culprit. Instead, I create a data.frame after dumping the list of sentences into a single vector. I am also able to compute the vector of corresponding filenames using the function `rep`.
2. Untested: assuming `merge()` was also computationally expensive, I used `rep()` again to append the `node` and `component`. You could check by yourself if this is instead faster this way.
3. I used the supposedly faster `readr::read_lines` instead of `readLines`
4. Your `matchFunction` is presumably a slow re-implementation of the `%in%` function
5. I replaced `mapply` with the faster `unlist(Map(...), use.names = FALSE)` construct. Also `sapply` with `vapply`. `mapply` and `sapply` are slower because they try to simplify your output data.
6. Where possible, I have avoided large duplications of your data, e.g. where you were using `mutate`. Instead, I just appended column(s) to your existing data

There are certainly more things that can be done. One thing that comes to mind is to use the `data.table` package instead of data.frames since you have such a large data. But please let us know first how much faster this code is. Maybe it won't be worth the extra effort.

Comment: This is looking very promising. However, you may notice that something goes wrong when using diacritics. Take for instance the file `attachécase` in the testdata. It isn't included in the resulting dataset. I have done some testing with encoding but I can't find the culprit. Whenever a filename/node/sentence contains a special character such as éàçè that node will never make it to the end results, even if the node can be found in the sentence. Any ideas? +1 for your efforts so far!

Comment: Is that not a problem with your original code though? Nothing I introduced, right?

Comment: I'm afraid you have. In my own code this isn't a problem.

Comment: It seems to go wrong when reading the lines in `e` with the readr package. The encoding is wrong. For the special characters, I need UTF-8.

Comment: After some digging I found that this is an issue with readr. See [this issue](https://github.com/hadley/readr/issues/40). [Here](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/04/09/readr-0-1-0/) it is stated that in future versions an encoding argument will be supported. For now it seems better for me to use the vanilla readLines. Don't you agree? Could you modify your code accordingly?

Comment: Sure, done. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Everything is working great! Thanks a lot. The only thing that's missing that I had in my original code is that for freqTable, the output CSV doesn't have an index column, even though the dataset itself has. Is there a way to add an index column to that frequency table?

Comment: An index column as in 1,2,3,etc. for the row index? Can you tell us how fast the code runs?

Comment: Yes exactly that. A column without column name numbering the rows. Starting from 1. And the results are astonishing so far. Instead of 40 minutes the script runs in 10 minutes!!!

Comment: Thx. Try replacing the `cbind` line near the end with `cbind(index = seq_len(nrow(.)), node = row.names(.), .)`.