# Function to rebalance portfolio

Tags: python, performance

I wrote a small code in Python to conduct a backtest. My `rebalance` function is very slow and I would like to improve it. I need to profile it but I would welcome any opinion on how to refactor my code nicely.

```python
def Rebalance(self, currentDate, data, VolatilityForSizing,Wthtslippage=True):
        # Handle open positions
        yesterday = max(self.PtfHandler.Positions.index[self.PtfHandler.Positions.index<currentDate])
        CurrentPositions = self.PtfHandler.Positions.loc[yesterday]
        self.PtfHandler.Positions.loc[currentDate]=CurrentPositions.values
        OpenPositions = CurrentPositions[CurrentPositions !=0].keys()
        NotOpenPositions = set(CurrentPositions.keys())-set(OpenPositions)

        # Save Metrics in Ptf
        PositionPnL = dict.fromkeys(NotOpenPositions,0)
        PtfMetrics = dict()
        PtfMetrics['Date'] = currentDate
        PtfMetrics['TradedPositions'] = len(OpenPositions)
        SumReturn = 0

        # FirstSignal at current date from FirstSignalHandler
        FirstSignalSetMax = set(CurrentPositions[self.FirstSignalHandler.FirstSignalSetMax.loc[currentDate]].keys())
        FirstSignalSetMin = set(CurrentPositions[self.FirstSignalHandler.FirstSignalSetMin.loc[currentDate]].keys())

        goLongCandidate = self.SecondSignal.initiateLong.ix[currentDate]
        goShortCandidate = self.SecondSignal.initiateShort.ix[currentDate]

        goLongCandidate = goLongCandidate[goLongCandidate>0].keys() # turn goLongCandidate which is a serie into a list
        goShortCandidate = goShortCandidate[goShortCandidate>0].keys()

        PotentialLongToClose = set(CurrentPositions[CurrentPositions.isin(OpenPositions) & CurrentPositions>0].keys())
        LongToClose = list(PotentialLongToClose.intersection(FirstSignalSetMax))
        self.PtfHandler.Positions.loc[currentDate,LongToClose] = 0
        for stock in LongToClose:
            self.PtfHandler.saveStrategyEndDate(stock,currentDate)
            pnl = self.PtfHandler.getNonTradedPositionPnL(currentDate,yesterday,stock,CurrentPositions[stock],data,self.FirstSignalHandler.VolOnEntry)
            pnl = pnl + self.PtfHandler.getSlippageImpact(stock,CurrentPositions[stock],self.FirstSignalHandler.VolOnEntry,saveReturnWthSlippage=Wthtslippage)
            PositionPnL.update({stock:pnl})
            SumReturn = SumReturn + pnl

        PotentialShortToClose = set(CurrentPositions[CurrentPositions.isin(OpenPositions) & CurrentPositions<0].keys())
        ShortToClose = list(PotentialShortToClose.intersection(FirstSignalSetMin))
        self.PtfHandler.Positions.loc[currentDate,ShortToClose] = 0
        for stock in ShortToClose:
            self.PtfHandler.saveStrategyEndDate(stock,currentDate)
            pnl = self.PtfHandler.getNonTradedPositionPnL(currentDate,yesterday,stock,CurrentPositions[stock],data,self.FirstSignalHandler.VolOnEntry)
            pnl = pnl + self.PtfHandler.getSlippageImpact(stock,CurrentPositions[stock],self.FirstSignalHandler.VolOnEntry,saveReturnWthSlippage=Wthtslippage)
            PositionPnL.update({stock:pnl})
            SumReturn = SumReturn + pnl

        NewPotentialLong = set(goLongCandidate).intersection(NotOpenPositions)
        NewPotentialLong = list(NewPotentialLong.intersection(FirstSignalSetMax))
        for stock in NewPotentialLong:
            self.PtfHandler.saveStrategyStartDate(stock,currentDate)
            qty = self.AssetManager.getNewTradeWeight(currentDate, stock,VolatilityForSizing)
            self.PtfHandler.Positions.loc[currentDate,stock] =qty
            pnl = self.PtfHandler.getSlippageImpact(stock,qty,self.FirstSignalHandler.VolOnEntry,saveReturnWthSlippage=Wthtslippage)
            PositionPnL[stock]=pnl
            SumReturn = SumReturn + pnl

        NewPotentialShort = set(goShortCandidate).intersection(NotOpenPositions)
        NewPotentialShort = list(NewPotentialShort.intersection(FirstSignalSetMin))
        for stock in NewPotentialShort:
            self.PtfHandler.saveStrategyStartDate(stock,currentDate)
            qty = self.AssetManager.getNewTradeWeight(currentDate, stock,VolatilityForSizing)
            self.PtfHandler.Positions.loc[currentDate,stock] =-qty
            pnl = self.PtfHandler.getSlippageImpact(stock,qty,self.FirstSignalHandler.VolOnEntry,saveReturnWthSlippage=Wthtslippage)
            SumReturn = SumReturn + pnl
            PositionPnL[stock]= pnl

        # Save portfolio positions and returns given rebalancing
        NotTradedPositions = list(set(OpenPositions)-set(ShortToClose)-set(LongToClose))
        for stock in NotTradedPositions:
            pnl = self.PtfHandler.getNonTradedPositionPnL(currentDate,yesterday,stock,CurrentPositions[stock],data,self.FirstSignalHandler.VolOnEntry)
            SumReturn = SumReturn + pnl
            PositionPnL.update({stock:pnl})

        self.PtfHandler.AdjustedReturns = self.PtfHandler.AdjustedReturns.append(PositionPnL,ignore_index=True)
        PtfMetrics['PtfAdjReturn'] = SumReturn
        YesterdayCumReturn = self.PtfHandler.PtfAdjustedReturns.ix[-1]['CumReturn'] if not self.PtfHandler.PtfAdjustedReturns.empty else 0
        PtfMetrics['CumReturn'] = YesterdayCumReturn + SumReturn
        self.PtfHandler.PtfAdjustedReturns = self.PtfHandler.PtfAdjustedReturns.append(PtfMetrics,ignore_index=True)
```

Edit:
I just profiled the function. The first calculation to get yesterday date is very costly - which I thought. `DataFrame.append` is also very costly. Same for the PnL calculation. I probably need to improve the function.

Comment: Step 1: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/. Step 2: That should be more than one function.

Comment: Pandas dataframes are very very slow to build row-by-row.  See [my recent answer](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/101809/76662) where I profiled the code in the question and found that changing from row-by-row construction with `append` was 20x slower than building regular vanilla Python lists of each column and then constructing the dataframe by column.

Answer (score 3):

As jonrsharpe said, read the style guide for Python, [PEP0008](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). One of the first things it will suggest is that you stick to just 4 spaces for indentation, but at the very least you should always use the exact same amount of indentation across your whole script.

It also suggests that you keep line lengths to under 79 characters and that you always leave a space between operators so I'd change this:

```
yesterday = max(self.PtfHandler.Positions.index[self.PtfHandler.Positions.index<currentDate])
```

into this:

```
yesterday = max(self.PtfHandler.Positions.index[
                self.PtfHandler.Positions.index < currentDate])
```

In particular you shouldn't have an asymmetric application of this. You really shouldn't ever do `CurrentPositions !=0`, ideally `CurrentPositions != 0` but `CurrentPositions!=0` is better.

You should also add spaces to comma separated lists. Treat it like written english where a list of apples, bananas, pears etc. will have spaces after each comma.

```
PositionPnL = dict.fromkeys(NotOpenPositions, 0)
```

It probably seems redundant there, but makes a big difference here:

```
pnl = self.PtfHandler.getNonTradedPositionPnL(currentDate,yesterday,stock,CurrentPositions[stock],data,self.FirstSignalHandler.VolOnEntry)
```

All that runs together and is harder to read. I'd prefer

```
pnl = self.PtfHandler.getNonTradedPositionPnL(currentDate, yesterday, stock, 
                      CurrentPositions[stock], data, self.FirstSignalHandler.VolOnEntry)
```

Why use `dict()` instead of `{}`? It's arguably less clear to call the function and offers no real advantage.

Why are `goLongCandidate` and `goShortCandidate` evaluated separately? Here they're identical, they are changed later but it'd be neater to just evaluate one and then make a copy of it for the other.

Also inline comments should be short, if they're running long on an already wrong line, put them on the next line or previous one. Really though, the comment feels unnecessary to me since the line is quite clear in what it does.

```
goLongCandidate = goLongCandidate[goLongCandidate>0].keys() # turn goLongCandidate which is a serie into a list
```

This line can be shortened and made clearer with the `=+` operator, which just adds the value on the right to the current value of the variable on the left.

```
SumReturn = SumReturn + pnl
SumReturn += pnl
```

I'll make a note that in parameter arguments you *shouldn't* put whitespace either side of the `=` operator, so you were right to do that here:

```
self.PtfHandler.AdjustedReturns = self.PtfHandler.AdjustedReturns.append(PositionPnL,ignore_index=True)
```

...but still add the space after the comma.